# How to avoid backslashitis?

Tags: list, tcl

I have the following code:

```
proc list_backslash {} {

    array unset options
    array set options {
        -inputs {vdd}
        -outputs {vss}
    }

    set inputs { vdd2 vdd dvdd }
    set outputs { vss2 vss dvss }

    set updateOptions [ list \
        -inputs       $inputs \
        -outputs      $outputs ]

    array set options $updateOptions

    foreach {k v} [array get options] {
        puts "$k => $v"
    }
}
```

Since I have a lot of key-value pairs in `updateOptions`, there is a severe backslashitis! Is there a better way to do code `updateOptions`? I tried `subst` + braces `{}` and realized it does not preserve the list structure thus dooming it.

Comment: Line-continuation backslash in tcl is natural and is not usually considered ugly. If you find yourself writing a lot of tcl then learn to see it as not ugly. You can easily convince yourself of the other way around: not having the backslash for multi-line statements result in confusing or inconsistent grammar. Take javascript as one example where code that looks like it's doing something actually does something else because humans reading the code assume it's a multi-line statement but the interpreter unambiguously execute is as two independent statements. So not having backslash is ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you need to continue a line you have to use a quoting mechanism of some kind with Tcl. Otherwise, the command call ends when the line ends. The `[`brackets`]` can include multiple statements too; it's legal, but *really not recommended*.

But that does mean that sometimes you've got awkward alternatives. Perhaps you'll be best off with doing this:

```
set updateOptions {
    -inputs       $inputs
    -outputs      $outputs
}
foreach {key value} $updateOptions {
    set options($key) [subst $value]
}
```

The `array set` command isn't especially efficient until you get to huge numbers of options (many thousands) when the code is inside a procedure.

---

Or if you've got Tcl 8.6, `dict map` is perhaps better:

```
array set options [dict map {key value} $updateOptions {subst $value}]
```

Be aware that `subst` is not a particularly efficient command in Tcl 8.6 except when used with a literal argument. That's because with variable arguments, it compiles them to bytecode at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

option a) Put it all on one line.

option b) Structure the code as:

```
 set options(-inputs) $inputs
 set options(-outputs) $outputs
```

option c) Learn to like backslashes.